# JavaScript looping through an array to check for numeric values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an an array that returns the values such as the following:

```
//Eg 1    [ [ "214323", "34243" ], [ "3333", "123" ] ]

//Eg 2    [ [ "214323" ],[ "3333" ] ]
```

I want to validate if the array holds only numbers with no spaces or null, else I would like to throw an error.
This is my following code and it does not work in the above example. It throws out an error even though all values are numeric.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= arrayVals.length; i++) {
    if(!(/^\d+$/.test(arrayVals[i]))) {
        err_comp=true;

        }   
}

if( err_comp ==true) {
        alert( 'The value has to be only numeric.');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an **array of arrays**, thus you need ***two*** loops:

```
var err_comp = false;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayVals.length; i++) {
  var arr = arrayVals[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (!(/^\d+$/.test(arr[j]))) {
        err_comp = true;
    }   
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you'd be testing `/^\d+$/.test([ "214323", "34243" ])`.

Answer (score 2):

you should not use `<=` because you start with 0 you should use `<`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayVals.length;
```

Comment: But `isNaN` won't throw any error with something like `' 10 '`, but he doesn't want spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
multi_arr.every(function(arr) {
    return arr.every(function(n) {
        return /^\d+$/.test(n);
    });
});
```

You can change the test as you need, and you can add a [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Compatibility) patch for IE8 if you want.

And you can make reusable your functions.

```
function forEveryArray(fn) {
    return function every_array(arr) {
        return arr.every(fn)
    }
}

function isNumber(n) { return /^\d+$/.test(n); }


multi_arr.every(forEveryArray(isNumber));
```

Comment: While it's a good solution, this won't work for versions of IE < 9.

Comment: @João: That should be considered a feature, no? ;)